# Can I show a color from its hex value in *any* file?

Tags: syntax-highlighting, highlight

We have [vim-css-color](https://github.com/skammer/vim-css-color) to display colors in .css files. Currently I'm editing my i3wm config to match colors to a new terminal theme and it would be quite handy to be able to actually *see colors* I'm dealing with. **Is there a plugin that would highlight colors in any file**?

I tried to use the above mentioned plugin by renaming a `config` to `config.css` but it still misses a couple of colors. Here is a comparison of what `atom` (first picture) does and what `nvim` (second picture) does:

[image: atom color highlighting] 
[image: nvim with vim-css-color highligting]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I made a plugin [Colorizer](https://github.com/chrisbra/Colorizer) That should do what you want. Read the help for more information.

Comment: That's exactly what I was searching for! Many thanks!